# QR decomposition

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-decomposition, qr-decomposition

Is there a way to implement a QR decomposition like in [Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qr.html?searchHighlight=qr&s_tid=srchtitle_qr_1)? In particular, I am interested in the following command:

`[C,R,P] = qr(S,B)`

According to the description it "returns a permutation matrix P that is chosen to reduce fill-in in R. You can use C, R, and P to compute a least-squares solution to the sparse linear system S*X = B with X = P*(R\C)".

I need to run the Python equivalent of the MATLAB code `[Q, R, E] = qr(X,0);`

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.linalg.qr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr.html#scipy-linalg-qr) provides the functionality you're looking for when given the argument `pivoting=True`.

Comment: I don't understand where to specify B. I need to run the Python equivalent of the MATLAB code [Q, R, E] = qr(X,0);